# Livestreet CMS (Вытащить пользователей не в таблицу, а в несколько <div> блоков)

Tags: php, html, livestreet

Нужно вытащить данные (аватар, линк на профиль страницы) не в таблицу, как делается, а в 30 разных `<div>` блоков. 
Загвоздка в том,

```
{if $aUsersList}
{foreach from=$aUsersList item=oUserList}
{assign var="oSession" value=$oUserList->getSession()}
{assign var="oUserNote" value=$oUserList->getUserNote()}
```

как поочередно заполнить эту тучу блоков из БД? Буду премного благодарен советом.

Answer (score 1):

Вы планируете сверстать всё вручную?

Есть простой, хоть и не совсем *правильный* способ.

В файле `templates\skin\synio\user_list.tpl` (привожу пример для темы `synio`), вы можете удалить всю табличную верстку вообще.

А внутри цикла для каждого `ID` прописать собственную верстку. Заодно в этом случае можно в конце записать `div` по умолчанию.

```
{if $aUsersList}
    {foreach from=$aUsersList item=oUserList}
        {assign var="oSession" value=$oUserList->getSession()}
        {assign var="oUserNote" value=$oUserList->getUserNote()}
        {if $oUserList->getId() == 1}
            <a href="{$oUserList->getUserWebPath()}"><img src="{$oUserList->getProfileAvatarPath(48)}" alt="avatar" class="avatar" /></a>
            <div class="name {if !$oUserList->getProfileName()}no-realname{/if}">
                <p class="username word-wrap"><a href="{$oUserList->getUserWebPath()}">{$oUserList->getLogin()}</a></p>
                {if $oUserList->getProfileName()}<p class="realname">{$oUserList->getProfileName()}</p>{/if}
            </div>
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```